# windows forms listbox add item while it is not created

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I wonder how it works!!!

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Created.ToString());
}
```

it print `false`. **why???** when this control get created? i thought `InitializeComponent()` create controls. but it likes that i doesn't create controls completely! and **how it add item while it is not created???**

P.S: i ask this question because i like to use `listBox1.Invoke` in constructor to print some logs. I use `invoke` because my program use multiple threads. but please focus on my question not on why I need it. thanks!

Comment: Override the Form's `OnCreateControl()` method instead of using its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Because during ``()`is object`listBox1` only construct, alocated on heap and defined.
You can see this basically with

```cs
InitializeComponent();          
listBox1.Items.Add(listBox1 is object); //Returns true
```

But whole form is rendered after `Form` constructor.
You can avoid this issue by not writing your code in constructor (Because basically it's supposed to construct objects, not doing other things).
Instead of constructor, write your code as reaction on Load event, like this:

```cs
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Created.ToString());
            this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Created.ToString());
        }
```

Load event is invoked after constructing (while method `Application.Run(new Form1());` si called) and you have guarantee, that everything is Created.

**How it add item while it is not created?**
Basically because adding item to listbox is separated for adding to collection and render it.

This code add all items and then rendering is called

```cs
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
```

So you can add an Item, because memory exist and rendering is just not called.
After the visual listbox1 is created is rendered with items.

Reason for throwing Exception during the Invoke is basicily the uncompletion of listbox construction. I think it is only a security precaution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i already knew that i can use form_load event. but the main point of this question is how i can add item to a non-created control but it accept it and show it! while i can't use invoke to do this! it is complicated!